# Looking for linear non polar compound which is used heavily due to its boiling or melting temperature or its density

Tags: everyday-chemistry

So my son was given an exercise to find some linear non polar compound that is used heavily due to convenient boiling or melting temperatures or its density.

Having no training in chemistry I have no idea how to help him. I tried to look for a kind of search engine for chemicals just to see what kinds of compounds fit the bill, but I cannot find anything.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you arrange your reply as an answer? I understand you are talking about CO2.

Comment: OK. I googled and CO2's boiling temperature is just under -78 Celsius. So, does it have to do anything with the process you described?

Comment: As I understand, I need to read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercritical_fluid_extraction to understand the essence of your answer.

Comment: I would not understand much depth anyway. I just want to understand what makes CO2 such a popular SF.

Comment: Why not some look up data on hydrocarbon oils, there is a huge choice there.

Comment: Warning. We, or the exercise, must be precise. CO2 has no electrical dipole moment but don't qualify as apolar. It is indeed a polar molecule / solvent.

Comment: @porphyrin - I really know little about the subject. But I thank you for the feedback, I hope it will be useful to my son.

Answer (score 1):

*A* possible answer is [*n*-octane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octane),

[image]

([image credit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octane))

for what it

- consists of linear organic molecules (*vide infra*)
- has a boiling point of about $125\,\pu{^\circ{}C}$ / $257\,\pu{^\circ{}F}$
- is a hydrocarbon you either find in, or generate from natural oil

A bit on the *n* in *n*-octane:  This is a shorthand for *normal*, because the carbon atoms are consecutively bound to each other in an open chain.  Which is not the same as if they would form branched molecules, then denoted *iso*-octane.  A prominent *iso*-octane (*iso* as in *isomer*, i.e. same number of atoms per molecule, but different spatial arrangment) is 2,2,4-trimethylpentane:

[image]

([image credit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2,2,4-Trimethylpentane))

Blend in mixtures of the two, they serve as in [octane rating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octane_rating) of fuels.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but n-octane does not look like a linear molecule.

Comment: I agree with you that even if it was called «linear», _n_-octane is not as straight as a pen, or like acetylene (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acetylene).  This zig-zag shape is a result how the carbon atoms bind together, and like thread, these may be twisted, too (e.g. in polymers, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymer#Microstructure).  This however contrasts to branching (like the _iso_-octane), or even forming rings as, e.g. in cyclohexane (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclohexane).

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying, but it seems to me the ask is for something like acetylene (geometrically) after all.